# Existence of topological space whose open sets are anti-closed under infinite intersection

Tags: general-topology

Is there an infinite topology $T$, such that whenever $I$ is an infinite set of open sets of $T$ which does not contain the empty set, then $\bigcap I$ is not an open set?

Comment: I think the "finite complement topology" satisfies what you need.

Comment: @azif00: The OP wants it to hold for **all** infinite families of non-empty open sets.

Comment: @Yuval: The cofinite topology does not work: take the family where each element is missing a single point, and ever point is missing from one  of the sets in the family. The intersection will be empty, hence open.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I see, thanks for point my mistake.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: you are right. I only thought about countable families.

Comment: @Yuval: Even then it might fail, since the underlying set could be countable. But there is an easy twist to fix the problem, which I'm writing up.

Comment: Start with the cofinite topology on an infinite set, and add a new point that is in every non-empty open set.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I swear I was almost done writing that before you posted. I guess given the less-than-a-minute time difference, that should be clear, but just thought I would say it out loud.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Yes, yours appeared very quickly after I posted my comment; I had just time enough to wonder whether your easy twist was going to be the same as mine — as indeed it was. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cofinite topology suggested by Yuval is *almost* right, but not quite, because you can have an infinite intersection be empty even if none of the sets being intersected is itself empty. But a small twist to it will fix it.

Let $Y$ be an infinite set, let $\infty$ be something not in $Y$, and let $X=Y\cup\{\infty\}$. We define a topology $\tau$ on $X$ as follows: for $A\subseteq X$, $A\in\tau$ if and only if $A=\varnothing$, or else
$$\infty\in A\text{ and }|X\setminus A|\lt\infty.$$

This is a topology: it includes $\varnothing$ by definition;  it includes $X$ itself. If $A$ and $B$ are in $\tau$ then $A\cap B\in\tau$, since the complement of $A\cap B$ is the union of $X\setminus A$ and $X\setminus B$, two finite sets. And if $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a family of open sets, at least one of which, say $A_j$, is nonempty, then $\cup A_i$ contains $\infty$ and has complement contained in $X\setminus A_j$, hence finite.

Now assume that $\{B_i\}_{i\in I}$ is an infinite family of nonempty open sets. I claim that if $\cap B_i$ is open, then there are actually only finitely many distinct $B_i$ (and as a consequence, if the family contains infinitely many *pairwise distinct* $B_i$, then the intersection is not open).

Indeed, $\cap B_i$ is not empty since $\infty\in \cap B_i$. If $\cap B_i$ is open, then it has finite complement, so there exists a finite set $F$ such that $X\setminus (\cap B_i) = F$. Since
$$F = X\setminus (\cap B_i) = \cup(X\setminus B_i),$$
it follows that there are only finitely many possibilities for $X\setminus B_i$, which in turn means there are only finitely many possibilities for the $B_i$. Thus, our infinite family consists of only finitely many distinct sets.

By contrapositive, if the family includes infinitely many pairwise distinct sets, then $\cap B_i$ must have infinite complement, and since $\cap B_i\neq\varnothing$, it follows that it is not open.

Thus, this topology satisfies the required conditions.